# Maven: configure parallel build in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Maven has a capability to perform parallel builds:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

```
mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads
mvn -T 1C clean install # 1 thread per cpu core
mvn -T 1.5C clean install # 1.5 thread per cpu core
```

Is it possible to specify this arguments in pom.xml or settings.xml? Repeating this options could be annoying.

Comment: It is not possible to define the `-T..` option in pom cause it does not belong there nor in the settgins.xml file. Why do you need to repeat it? Using a continious integration there you will do the configuration only once?

Comment: I perform build many times during a day on my local machine

Comment: If you using unix add alias for this command. For example, alias paralel_mvn='mvn -T 4 clean install'.

Comment: If you using windows write a simple batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run maven build multithreaded all the time by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363957/how-to-run-maven-build-multithreaded-all-the-time-by-default)

Comment: @Sergey how can it be a duplicate when my question was created 5 years ago and question you referring was created 2 months ago :) ?

Answer (score 4):

This solution is a bit of a hack but worked for me. It involves specifying a new environment variable, assigning the value -T3 to it and adding this variable to the Maven launch script.

For Windows (Linux in parens):

1. Open the Environment Variables window: Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System settings -> Environment Variables
2. Add the property *MAVEN_CMD_LINE_OPTS* with your desired value. In my case `-T 3` as I want Maven to use 3 threads to build in parallel.
3. Edit the *mvn.cmd* file (In Linux: the *mvn* file). Find the part where the Java command is actually executed, the line starting with *%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE%* (In Linux: generally after the line defining the main class: *org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher*)
4. Add %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_OPTS% to the end of the line (In Linux: $MAVEN_CMD_LINE_OPTS)

When you run *mvn compile* on a Maven project you will now see the following line:

*Using the MultiThreadedBuilder implementation with a thread count of 3*

This has the advantage of the user being able to 'override' this value. So if the user executes *mvn -T4 compile*, then 4 threads are used instead of the default 3.

Note:

1. I tried this on Maven 3.3.9 but the concept should work on any Maven
   version.
2. Multi-threaded builds can suffer from issues where plugins
   especially custom plugins are not thread safe. So use with care and
   consider disabling this as a fix in case of issues.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm using maven 3.8 in Eclipse 2019-6 on Windows 10. Rather than putting it at the end of the `%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE%` line, it made more sense to put it on that line after `%MAVEN_OPTS%`.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way to configure this in the pom.xml or settings.xml  There is a good solution on unix systems, edit your .bashrc and add an alias.

```
alias mvnp='mvn -T 4'
```

now from the terminal run maven using mvnp

```
mvnp clean install
```

Answer (score -4):

You are able to specify the option in the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html). Once this is done, you don't have to repeat it. Configuring the environment variable depends on your system. However this will affect all maven runs within your environment. Maybe it's possible for you to enable different environments, so that only the project you actually want to build in parallel is running in such an environment.

Comment: As far as I am aware `MAVEN_OPTS` can only be used to specify JVM properties. The `-T` option is a maven specific option and so `MAVEN_OPTS` can not be used to pass this option to maven. I am happy to be corrected if wrong on this.

Comment: I agree - you can not set ``-T`` in ``MAVEN_OPTS``.  It leads to an error: ```Unrecognized option: -T0.5C
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```