# How to run maven build multithreaded all the time by default

Tags: java, maven, command-line

I want to spare the time typing a -T3 on the command line as I want all the maven builds I will ever do to run multithreaded.

Maven 3.3.9
I googled but didn't find anything promising, only the suggestion to add an environment variable for command line opts and append that to every maven call on commandline.

[Maven: configure parallel build in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720014/maven-configure-parallel-build-in-pom-xml)

This way, every time, still a manual step is required (entering the environment variable's name) to do a parallel build.

I'd like to configure that globally in the mvn settings.xml file.

Comment: The question is: Why do you need it every time? Usually this is usefull in CI solution to reduce the feedback time ?

Comment: I want to reduce compile time whenever possible

Comment: Are you doing that often on command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't configure thing like this `settings.xml`. This can be configured differently since [Maven 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html).

You can use a file `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config` which contains the options given on command like within the root directory of your project which simply can contain:

```
-T 3
```

but this is limited on a project base not always.