# How to override maven offline settings

Tags: maven, command-line-arguments

As of my previous question, I now use a per project mvn config file.
(see [How to run maven build multithreaded all the time by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363957/how-to-run-maven-build-multithreaded-all-the-time-by-default/57364222#57364222))

I added -T 3 and -offline arguments to speed up compiling. But when colleagues changed some dependencies and I need those changes locally, I want to get them quickly, not having to go to the config file, open it, save it, run maven, change the config file back to offline.

Googled but didn't find a solution

maven.config:

```
-T 3 -offline
```

I'd like to run just `mvn clean install` most if the cases and something like `mvn clean install -online` when I was told that I need to update dependencies.

Comment: In the standard settings, Maven updates dependencies daily. Doesn't that fit for you?

Comment: In standard settings, maven still contacts the repo on every build, event after doing a mvn clean install -U once before.
I want my default to be offline. Also, sometimes I need to change dependencies locally, build them and use the local build (I use the -U option for that). I don't want to get any artifact from the artifact repository which might have been built by CI in the meantime.

Comment: I mean, you should just ask yourself why your workflow differs from everybody else ... Maven contacts the repository, that may take a short amount of time, but does not really hurt. Furthermore, for using local builds, you _don't_ use -U, but just build. If your update policy is daily, you get your own version most of the time. If you want to be sure to have the local version, just change the version number to something like 1.2.3-TEST-SNAPSHOT.